# Reactjs - How manually cache SPAs to serve for Googlebot

Tags: php, reactjs, caching, single-page-application, prerender

I have a Reactjs application with Codeigniter(php) as the Back-End. For some reasons I can’t use server side rendering. I tried using prerender.io but I’ve read more or less about pros and cons about using this amazing website!
Is there any way to cache manually pages to serve to Googlebot? Something like prerender.io prerender pages by caching! There are only 60 pages!

Google can render my pages as well but in fetch section, there is no page content’s code!

At the end, My pages not exist is SERP!!

Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Prerender.io on the free plan with 60 pages. Feel free to send us an email if you need help getting set up!

Comment: actually I keep in touch with Todd! But unfortunately there is no answer or I think he is working on it because I have problem with installing prerender.io! I have red error which is say there is no request for Token. I enabled three modes option. I check it with https://service.prerender.io/https://www.mokaab.ir and the page source is work fine!

Comment: Great! Let's continue the conversation there and we'll make sure to help get things working.